# Rails 4 JQuery .js.erb cannot set click event that renders a partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-events, erb

I have a remote true button that on click goes a controller method and then executes the .js.erb.  I am rendering a partial in the .js.erb and then I would like to set a click event for a button within that partial with renders another partial.  The click event is not being set.  I think Rails reads the ruby first in .js.erb, but does it read the ruby within the click event?

Any guidance on how to execute this correctly would be great!

**.js.erb**

```
$("#new-user-family-form").children().last().replaceWith("<%= j render(:partial => 'new_family_member', :locals => {:new_user => @new_user}) %>");

$("#remove-new-family-member-button").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#new-user-family-form").children().last().replaceWith("<%= j render(:partial => 'new_user_complete') %>");
});
```

Comment: Is button `#remove-new-family-member-button` placed in partial `new_family_member`? You may try this `$(document).on("click", "#remove-new-family-member-button", function(e) {` instead of `$("#remove-new-family-member-button").on("click", function(e){`

Comment: @MicFin I am also facing same problem, it does not solve the problem

Comment: I understand Kien Thanh, and for me, it works for some events (like click, mouseenter..) but not for load event of a image, Do yoy know how to do for load images events?